# Copy extra files after build with Nix

Tags: rust, nix

I have a Nix flake which uses this:

```
bin = craneLib.buildPackage (commonArgs // {
  inherit cargoArtifacts;
});
```

to create a binary executable in `./result/bin/exkecutabel`

Now I need some more files to go next to it in the `bin/` folder. How do I get them there?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it's possible to use a `postInstall` script that uses the `$out` environment variable and copy the files.

Like so:

```hs
bin = craneLib.buildPackage (commonArgs // {
            inherit cargoArtifacts;
            postInstall = ''
              install .env 20221002.sqlite $out/bin
            '';
});
```